# Pandas read_json with int64 values raises ValueError: Value is too big

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read in json files into dataframes.

```
df = pd.read_json('test.log', lines=True)
```

However there are values which are int64 and Pandas raises:

```
ValueError: Value is too big
```

I tried setting `precise_float` to `True`, but this didn't solve it.

It works when I do it line by line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
with open('test.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

However this is very slow. Already for files around 50k lines it takes a very long time.

Is there a way I can set the value of certain columns to use int64?

Comment: @Ben.T when setting the chunksize this returns an iterator object. But if I then try to loop over it with `for i in df:` it raises the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After updating pandas to a newer version (tested with 1.0.3), [this workaround](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26068#issuecomment-550900208) by  [artdgn](https://github.com/artdgn) can be applied to overwrite the `loads()` function in `pandas.io.json._json`, which is ultimately used when `pd.read_json()` is called.

Copying the workaround in case the links above stop working:

```py
import pandas as pd

# monkeypatch using standard python json module

import json

pd.io.json._json.loads = lambda s, *a, **kw: json.loads(s)

# monkeypatch using faster simplejson module
import simplejson
pd.io.json._json.loads = lambda s, *a, **kw: simplejson.loads(s)

# normalising (unnesting) at the same time (for nested jsons)
pd.io.json._json.loads = lambda s, *a, **kw: pandas.json_normalize(simplejson.loads(s))
```

After overwriting the `loads()` function with 1 of the 3 methods described by [artdgn](https://github.com/artdgn), `read_json()` also works with `int64`.

Comment: Setting the dtype to np.int64 raises the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You are right. sorry... would [this workaround](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26068#issuecomment-550900208) help you? Also it looks like it [was fixed in version 0.23.0 of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/cf9f51336b0ca99ef7ed686481e406c559ffb3d4). What is your version?

Comment: I saw this as well, but that code raises `AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.json' has no attribute '_json'`

Comment: I am on pandas v 1.0.3 and `pandas.io.json._json.loads()` is there.

Comment: I was using version 0.24.1, but removed that and installed 1.0.3 and it works now. Just around 55 extra columns are added with NaN values. But with a little cleaning it works and loads the data fast. Thanks.

Comment: I edited about the version. Was the workaround also necessary? -- OK I thought about it myself and I guess the workaround described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26068#issuecomment-550900208) was not necessary, otherwise the loading wouldn't be fast. Could you please confirm this? So the answer would be complete.

Comment: Yes even with the new version it still gives the value too big error and I needed to first change the behavior of read_json().

Comment: Hey I edited the answer and I hope it is complete and clear now. Could you please confirm whether this is the case?

Comment: I've removed some of the info which wasn't necessary for the solution and changed the code to remove the deprecation warning. But thanks and congrats on your first answer!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking time to polish the answer. It really is more to the point now. And I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20599).
The decoding of big numbers is still not implemented in the pandas' fork of the ultrajson library. The closest [implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/34984) was not merged. Whatever it was, you can use the workarounds provided in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `duckdb` library:

```
import duckdb

df = duckdb.query('''
SELECT * 
FROM read_json('test.log', auto_detect=True, sample_size=100000)
''').to_df()
```

If needed, find the corresponding `read_json` options fitting your purpose at https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/json.html